# Iterator not looping

Tags: java, android, loops, iterator

In my project, the user inputs random letters. Then I iterate through `my_list` to see if any of those random letters appear in `my_list`. If so, I remove them from `my_list`.

Example:

`List<String> my_list` contains: `[a, b, c, d]`

`List<String> rand` contains: `[r, a]`

Goal: The `a` will be removed from `my_list`

Problem: The `Iterator` loops through `my_list` searching for the letter `r`. The letter `r` is not in `my_list`. But instead of continuing to the next letter `a`, the `iterator` exits the loop and the `a` still remains in `my_list`

Can someone please tell me why my loop keeps breaking after the first letter?

Here's my code:

```
public void removeLetters( List<String> my_list, List<String> rand ) {
    Iterator<String> i = my_list.iterator();
    for( String s : rand ) {
        while( i.hasNext() ) {
            Object o = i.next();
            if( o.toString().equals( s ) ) {
                i.remove();
                i = my_list.iterator();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I explained my problem good enough. Please let me know if I need to explain more in detail.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use `my_list.removeAll( rand );`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating the `Iterator` inside the for loop.

```
for(String s : rand) {
    Iterator<String> i = my_list.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why people downvote some answers that are not wrong apparently, and don't even leave a comment explaining why...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your inner loop you reach the end of i iterator with the first iteration of the outer loop. Then when the second iteration of the for begin, the iterator i hasNext method always return false and it seems that nothing is done, like you said.

You should re initialize your i iterator for each new s of your for

Comment: so just put it inside my for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
i.remove();
```

here is your problem. you must remove it from my_list as you explained.

so use

```
my_list.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, just use the one liner:

```
my_list.removeAll(rand);
```

You could also use the List's ability to remove objects by equality:

```
for(String s: rand) {
    my_list.remove(s);
}
```

If you do want to iterate, this is exactly what java.util.AbstractCollection does:

```
Iterator<String> it = my_list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (rand.contains(it.next())) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea why this was downvoted? I think removeAll gave me a bug so I had to be a bit more specific and iterate through every item in the list. But i can try it again.

Comment: Who knows - there's some strange people on stackoverflow. I'd be interested to know what the bug is.

Comment: The removeAll() is easily the most efficient because it only has to search through the underlying 'my_list' data once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the Iterator to its beginning before looping through for the next item.

Answer (score 0):

You can only go through an Iterator once. Think about it: once `i.hasNext()` returns `false`, you fall out of the inner loop, loop around the outer one, and call `i.hasNext()` again. Why would it start returning `true` now? 
Bottom line: you have to create a new iterator every time you restart the outer loop (basically move `my_list.iterator()` call inside the loop)
Better yet, iterate through the list once, and use `contains()` on the input list:

```
for(Iterator it = my_list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    if(rand.contains(it.Next()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

If the input list (rand) could be large enough for this to matter, you might want to convert it into a Set before the loop: `rand = new HashSet(rand);` this will make you algorithm linear rather than quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

IS there a reason why you just don't use contains?

```
public void removeLetters(List<String> my_list, List<String> rand)
{
    List<String> updatedList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String s : my_list) 
    {
        if (!rand.contains(s))
        {
            updatedList.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```